# Android service asynctask

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-asynctask, android-context

I am currently using a fragment that starts a service. The service uses a asynctask to make a connection to a server. I want to show a progress dialog when the app is connecting to the server. Problem is that tried passing the application context for the dialog and I get a token error.

I think I need my activity's context and I don't know how to pass it to the service so it can use it to pass it to the asynctask. The connection is realized on the onCreate() method of the service.

LogCat :

```
08-06 12:58:01.696: E/AndroidRuntime(16733): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     create service com.homedcs.pushservice.PushAlarm:    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for   an application
08-06 12:58:01.696: E/AndroidRuntime(16733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2564)
08-06 12:58:01.696: E/AndroidRuntime(16733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:181)
08-06 12:58:01.696: E/AndroidRuntime(16733):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1414)
08-06 12:58:01.696: E/AndroidRuntime(16733):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Service :

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    if(connection == null){
        try {
            connection = new PushConnection(getApplicationContext()).execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Asynctask :

```
public PushConnection(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: i hope u not useing UI in DoINBacground

Comment: post some code and logcat

Comment: asynctask has own progress dialog.. show your logcat

Comment: you have a service and you want to pass a context from Activity to Service? well [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

Comment: Service is a context, okay, I tried passing "this" from service, still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting Asynctask from service so send service object instead of applicationcontext as [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) as a context.

Comment: 08-06 14:15:11.450: E/AndroidRuntime(17660): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.homedcs.pushservice.PushAlarm: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: You will get BadTokenException exception if your are using context of an activity which is not on foreground so better use service.this as context

Comment: Ok thats may be because your activity is not on foreground right??

Comment: The activity is in the foreground, having a fragment that shows a page adapter.

Answer (score 1):

When you call do in background second thread starts And use Progress bars customization in on progress start.

try{

```
 connection = new PushConnection(className.this).execute().get();

 } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Just change getAppliactionContext to Class ref. Use this and give me reply

Answer (score 0):

Avoid porgress dialog. This is the best approach for a viewpager.

https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/eSCfnyTzFUx